# Create Azure Devops environment from script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli

I would like to create an Azure DevOps Pipeline Environment from Powershell.

[image]

Using Azure CLI or the Azure REST API however, I can not find any information on this. 
There are some notions about the environments in the release but that's not what I need.

When using the portal following URL is called "/_apis/distributedtask/environments" but can't find any information about this REST API endpoint.

Does anyone know how to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, If I check the network section when I create a new environment I can see it uses this api:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments
```

With this JSON body:

```
{
    "description":"",
    "name":"test"
}
```

I don't see it domunetd but it should work :)

Comment: Running this code:
$uriAccount = $BaseUri + "distributedtask/environments?api-version=5.1-preview"
$body = "@{description=""a"";name=""b""}" | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $azureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 
5e...","typeName":"System.NullReferenceException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"NullReferenceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Comment: Ok its fixed now, my body was wrong and it works with 

$body = @{"description"="a";"name"="b"} | ConvertTo-Json